# how to get data from another form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have three forms which are `homeUser.php`, `application.php`, and `payment.php`.
in `homeUser.php` I have this information with form details.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="numApplicant" name="numApplicant" placeholder="Total Applicant" /><br />
</div></div></div>
                    
<div class="input-group form-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i></span>
        <input type="radio" class="form-group" id="location" name="location" <?php if (isset($location) && $location=="Location A") echo "checked";?> value="Location A">Location A
        <input type="radio" class="form-group" id="location" name="location" <?php if (isset($location) && $location=="Location B") echo "checked";?> value="Location B">Location B
        <input type="radio" class="form-group" id="location" name="location" <?php if (isset($location) && $location=="Location C") echo "checked";?> value="Location C">location C                     
    </div>
</div>
```

So in form `application.php`, I can retrieve the id by using the code

```
<?php
 echo $_POST['numApplicant'];
 echo $_POST['location'];?>
```

However, I want to use the `numApplicant` and `location` in the third form also.
how should I call it in the third form?

Comment: Use session to store your data. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: all my form has been include session. but still cannot solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options.

1: Store in sessions
2. Have hidden fields on your subsequent forms and _POST the data into these, they'll get reposted on each step.